# Can reCaptcha be hacked?

Tags: captcha

ReCaptcha seems to be used even by google, and so I believe it works (at least most of the time). So how has nobody managed to hack it? I mean, they could just look into reCaptcha code to find the answer...

Comment: How can someone look at the code to find the answer? I'm not sure you've looked up to see how it works and you are working on pure speculation.

Comment: no, I was saying how they might find the answers like in google forms, going in and finding the right answer, and then using it to answer

Comment: That comment makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not known on the client side, the answer is processed by a server which decides if it's right or wrong.

An AI bot might be able to solve v1 or even v2 challenges.  But seeing as even Google uses Captcha as free training for their AI, it's not an easy feat.  As well, Google periodically ramps up the difficulty to attempt to stay ahead of these bots.

Comment: It really looks like you didn't do any looking around to know what recaptcha was or how it works